# How to speed up offset windowing in PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing

I am working on moving 70M rows from a source table to a target table and using a complete dump and restore it on the other end is not an option. I have decided to create a small SQL file that selects 1M rows at a time and inserts the rows to the new table (after some clean up). The problem becomes that I need to iterate over through the 70M rows with 1M chunks, and I just realised that every iteration is getting slower and slower.

Is there a way to create a partial index to speed up queries having OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1000000, OFFSET 1000000 LIMIT 1000000 etc?

Example:

Fast:

```
SELECT id FROM huge_table ORDER BY id OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1000000
```

Slower:

```
SELECT id FROM huge_table ORDER BY id OFFSET 1000000 LIMIT 1000000
```

Very slow:

```
SELECT id FROM huge_table ORDER BY id OFFSET 5000000 LIMIT 1000000
```

Comment: Your chunk "optimization" just creates another problem and is indeed just a distraction. What is the original problem?

Comment: The original problem is to move 70M rows (each row is large, it is very long text) to a new table in a different server using dblink()

Comment: How did you try it? I mean show obfuscated code.

Comment: This is the gist of it: https://gist.github.com/l1x/046d70f3e75a538ed03d I am selecting 1M ids from the old database creating a temp table. After that I move the tables using the IDs in the tmp table. Delete the tmp table, and repeat. This way I can fix problems and no need to start from scratch.

Comment: I mean the code without the chunk "optimization". Specially how the data is inserted into the new table where the problem probably is. If you are committed to the chunk "optimization" problem, I mean solution, then do not bother to answer.

Comment: I am going to go down this path for now, thank you very much for your offer though!